# Accssess to repository from .net core library

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to wrap some function in repository class in .net core library. But I get a mistake that my constructor doesn't have properly constructor. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my DBcontext code

```
 public class effMercContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public effMercContext(DbContextOptions<effMercContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
     public class EffMercDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<effMercContext>
{
    public effMercContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<effMercContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=pinchdb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        return new effMercContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

My repository class so far

```
public class EmployeeRepository
{
    public Employee GetByID(int id)
    {
        using (effMercContext db = new effMercContext())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course if you define a class that can only be instantiated by passing a particular argument to its constructor, and you then attempt to instantiate it without passing any arguments to the constructor, it's not going to work. Which part isn't obvious, the fact that your class's constructor requires an argument, that you're not passing any argument to your constructor, or the error resulting from it? Explaining which part is unclear allows answers to focus on that part.

Comment: I'm not clear, how to implement my repository. I want to make something like this [link](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#using-framework-provided-services), but in .net core library, and not in interface,  but in class

Comment: @ВасяПупкин But your question does not handle this topic. It's about an error in with your `DbContext`. Please ask a new question belong to this topic

Comment: @ВасяПупкин Does one of our answers solves your problem with the `DbContext`?

Comment: @rbr94 yes, but I got few more(

Comment: @ВасяПупкин Could you upvote then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your `EmployeeRepository` as following...

```
public class EmployeeRepository
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<effMercContext>();
    // add necessary options
    public Employee GetByID(int id)
    {
        using (effMercContext db = new effMercContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

To learn more you can follow [this](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you call the constructor without parameters here:

```
public Employee GetByID(int id) {
    using (effMercContext db = new effMercContext())
    {

    }
}
```

But in your `DbContext` class you only have a constructor with one parameter:

```
public class effMercContext : DbContext {
    public effMercContext(DbContextOptions<effMercContext> options)
        : base(options) {
    }
}
```

Look at this article to find out how to use `DbContextOptions`: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html